# How to send email using CodeIgniter email class? I have Namecheap Open-Xchange

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I'm trying to send an email if the user forgot his password. But it is not sending.. This is my code in my controller:

```
function _send_email($type, $email, &$data)
{
    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->email->from($this->config->item('webmaster_email', 'tank_auth'), $this->config->item('website_name', 'tank_auth'));
    $this->email->reply_to($this->config->item('webmaster_email', 'tank_auth'), $this->config->item('website_name', 'tank_auth'));
    $this->email->to($email);
    $this->email->subject(sprintf($this->lang->line('auth_subject_'.$type), $this->config->item('website_name', 'tank_auth')));
    $this->email->message($this->load->view('email/'.$type.'-html', $data, TRUE));
    $this->email->set_alt_message($this->load->view('email/'.$type.'-txt', $data, TRUE));
    $this->email->send();
}
```

What else do I need to set up to properly send this email? I have admin@domain.com account in open xchange.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know or have ever used Open Xchange but you must first be sure that your mailer software (in this case open xchange) supports one of the protocols that CodeIgniter uses:

1. Mail
2. Sendmail
3. SMTP

I'm almost sure that the third option would be the one you'll want. Just make sure SMTP connections are allowed to your xchange server.

After you succesfuly set up your email backend then you can configure codeigniter to use your xchange settings either in the config file or passing an array of parameters to the email class.

Check the [Email Class documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html).

Answer (score 0):

I put all my settings in the email configuration file (email.php):

```
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'mail.domain.com';
$config['smtp_port'] = 25;
$config['smtp_user'] = 'admin@domain.com';
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'password';
$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
```

Your configuration may vary. Check out this link: http://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/1179/2175/general-configuration-in-mail-clients-and-mobile-devices